# CSS Fade Delay?

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, fade

I'm trying to create a slideshow banner for my website, and my idea was to stack them using z-index, then have the one on top fade out to reveal the one beneath, then move itself to the bottom of the stack.

I didn't fully understand how the CSS fade rules would work, and it seems they are fading all images in the stack at once, rather than just the one on top.  Is there an elegant way to make the fade class follow the top image of the stack so it's only fading out when it's on top?

Any help would be appreciated...

```js
var slidePosition = 0;
fadeSlides();


function fadeSlides() {
  var i;
  var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    slide[i].style.zIndex = slide[i].style.zIndex + 1;
    slide[i].style.opacity = "1";
  }
  slidePosition++;
  if (slidePosition > slide.length) {
    slidePosition = 1
  }
  slide[slidePosition - 1].style.opacity = "0";
  slide[slidePosition - 1].style.zIndex = "0";
  setTimeout(fadeSlides, 3500);

}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.mySlides {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.fade {
  animation: fade 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 5">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h9HMwvD.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 4">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/inAYNo3.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8VHulyg.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wZzx8GU.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 1">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZPO4z3V.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 0">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yhuKaY8.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: [It's the Intersect!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEKXEe61w1k)

Comment: You could try removing the fade class from all the images and then only apply it to the one you're fading at the moment

Comment: the fade class will apply the fade to any element that it is attached to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temani Afif's answer will help make things look good with your current approach, but the more simple answer is, as others have commented, to just toggle a class on *one* slide at a time.

You can use the CSS `transition` property to do this a bit more simply, without having to involve `@keyframes`: give all slides a transition property, and then toggle `opacity` with the `fade` class. That way, when the `fade` class changes from one slide to another, the old slide will fade out while the new one simultaneously fades in.

You can also simplify things further by not bothering with a separate `z-index` for every slide. Instead of trying to literally stack the slides all on top of each other in a specific order, just worry about moving the correct one to the top of the pile, and don't worry about all the others underneath since you can't see them anyway.

```js
fadeSlides();


function fadeSlides() {
  var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("fade")[0];
  var nextSlide = slide.nextElementSibling;
  
  if (nextSlide) {
    nextSlide.classList.add('fade');
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides')[0].classList.add('fade');
  }
  slide.classList.remove('fade');

  setTimeout(fadeSlides, 3500);
}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.mySlides {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 1000ms ease;
}

.mySlides.fade {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h9HMwvD.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/inAYNo3.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8VHulyg.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wZzx8GU.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZPO4z3V.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yhuKaY8.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I've updated the code, and it's working perfectly now.  In the "var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("fade")[0];"  what is the [0] doing?  Is it just calling upon the 0th position in that node?  Since the code is switching off and on the 'fade' class, couldn't it just call for it without referring to a specific instance?  Also, I don't fully understand the "if(nextSlide)" statement.  What exactly is it comparing if there is no additional condition.  Is there a condition implied just in the fact that it exists?

Comment: @user580248 So `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of all the elements that match the selector you pass it (note that it's elements, plural). We have to pick out which element in that array we want to add the class to. But we're assuming that only one element on the page will actually have the `fade` class, so that means the element in question will always be the one in the array with index `0`. The `if (nextSlide) ...` part is checking whether a `nextElementSibling` of the slide with the `fade` class exists at all – in other words, whether we're on the last slide of the set.

Comment: @user580248 So basically we're saying if there's another slide after the slide with the fade class, give that next slide the `fade` class, otherwise give the first slide the `fade` class. (And then we remove the `fade` class from the old slide right after that.)

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `transition` as there is no need to use `animation` since you are changing the properties using JS

```js
var slidePosition = 0;
fadeSlides();


function fadeSlides() {
  var i;
  var slide = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    slide[i].style.zIndex = slide[i].style.zIndex + 1;
    slide[i].style.opacity = "1";
  }
  slidePosition++;
  if (slidePosition > slide.length) {
    slidePosition = 1
  }
  slide[slidePosition - 1].style.opacity = "0";
  slide[slidePosition - 1].style.zIndex = "0";
  setTimeout(fadeSlides, 3500);

}
```

```css
.slideshow-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.mySlides {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.fade {
  transition: opacity 1s, z-index 0s 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 5">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h9HMwvD.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 4">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/inAYNo3.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 3">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8VHulyg.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/wZzx8GU.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 1">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZPO4z3V.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade" style="z-index: 0">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/yhuKaY8.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew there must have been a simple solution, but am still learning, so couldn't quite get these on my own.  Cheers!